# jQuery animate() function

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a health bar (0% health = 0px width; 100% health = 100px):

```
<div style="width:<?php echo $health ?>"><?php echo $health ?></div>
```

After the user clicks an "Heal" button, he receives some health. Using the `animate()` function I made the bar to increase its width.

But I also need something else: to update the health value that is inside the div. I would like to animate this too (to have the same increasing values as the width).

But I don't know how. Can you help me please?

L.E.:

```
$('div').animate({ width: data.newhealth }, duration: 1500);
```

It's inside a getJSON function.

I thought the solution would be to replace the div's content with `$('div').attr('width')` very often during the animation, but I don't know how to do this either.

Comment: can we see your animate function call?

Comment: You can't use the `animate` function *per se* to change actual content values.  You'll have to do this with a callback during the width animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `step` option to the animate function.  I have a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WxecS/) here: http://jsfiddle.net/WxecS/

The important bit is:

```
$('#healer').click(function() {
    $('#div').animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, {
        step: function(now, fx) {
            $(this).text(Math.floor(now) + '%');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Nice one... and better than what I was thinking.  I was [trying to use setInterval](http://jsfiddle.net/JYGqa/1/) :\ oh well. +1

Comment: +1, I was interested in the best solution to this question. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

use complete callback of `.animate()`
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
  $('#health').animate({
    width: 40
  },{ duration: 1000, step: function() {
    $("#health").text($(this).width());
  }});
```

Comment: that won't actually animate it though :\  The poster wanted to animate the text it sounds like.

Comment: It won't animate the text. The solution is to show the `$('div').attr('width')` repeatedly during the `animate` function.

Answer (score 1):

This wont animate the text, but will change it at the end:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ncv7Z/4/

```
$('#animate').animate({
    width: '100px'
}, 3000, function(){
    this.innerHTML = $(this).width();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the **step:** function like described on [jquery site](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)